# How to clear previous lines from StreamWriter?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

```
void BuildProjects()
{
    String outputPath = @"D:\PIT\ProcessImprovementTool\DLL";
    console = new Process();
    console.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    console.Exited += new EventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("if (console.Exited) --> ExitCode: " + console.ExitCode);
        BuildProjects();
    });
    console.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
    console.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ConsoleOutputHandler);
    console.Start();
    using (StreamWriter sw = console.StandardInput)
    {
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        console.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("D:\\PIT\\ProcessImprovementTool\\callVcvars32.bat");
            sw.WriteLine("cls");
            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 5; ctr++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("msbuild /property:OutputPath=" + outputPath + @";OutputType=Library " + lines[ctr]);
                //console.BeginOutputReadLine();
                sw.Flush();
            } 
        }
        if (tryout)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working");
        }
        sw.Close();
        //sw.Flush();
    }
    console.BeginOutputReadLine();
    console.BeginErrorReadLine();
    //console.WaitForExit();
    counter++;
}
```

in the

```
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 5; ctr++)
{
    sw.WriteLine("msbuild /property:OutputPath=" + outputPath + @";OutputType=Library " + lines[ctr]);
    //console.BeginOutputReadLine();
    sw.Flush();
}
```

if i set the limit for ctr to 40 (ctr < 40) my application hangs, and I get that the stream is already at its limit.

Based on my research, `.Flush()` should do the trick. or setting `AutoFlush` to `True`, but doesn't seem to work.

so how do I clear previous stream records, or anything that would let me input more than 40 lines? (i got 100+ but not more than 150 lines to write in streamWriter).

`lines` variable stores the value of "build.txt".

```
void readFromBuild()
{
    doneReading = true;
    lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\PIT\ProcessImprovementTool\Build\build.txt");
    //System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(lineCount);
    lineCount = lineCount - limit;
}
```

"build.txt" contains all files to be compiled to produce DLL files.

Comment: What is this "lines"? i didn't find it declared anywhere inside your code!

Comment: Do You want to clear all previous lines?
Or just last line ?
you can have a try on this 
`using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileToClear))
{
sw.Write("");
}
`

Comment: uhmm.. it is not actually stored in a file..

ill edit it sir

Comment: If your application hangs, it's because the console isn't reading stdin at the moment and you filled the buffer. You're not going to be able to go back in time and undo the data you've already written. All you can do is set things up so that your input is eventually consumed. But you haven't provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, so there's no way to actually _answer_ the question as written.

Comment: @PeterDuniho .. look at the "ctr".. if it is more than 30 around 40 i guess.. it hangs.. but if only below 30.. it runs perfectly..

Comment: You already said as much in your post. So? As I said, it's hanging because you filled the stdin buffer, so further writes block (i.e. hang your program). The stdin buffer gets filled because the process you started isn't reading from it. The reason for that depends on the process. Without a good [mcve], no one can tell you what that particular process is doing.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i already found another way to solve my problem :).. i just looped the whole process up.. and waited for the process to exit before continuing... :) ..

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks for the comment btw

Comment: Deadlock is an easy accident when you redirect I/O.  But easy to fix in this case, it is caused by calling BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine() too late.  So the process can't write enough of the output that's generated from the input commands and hangs.  Which in turn stops it from reading input and that causes the StreamWriter to hang.  Just move those two statements before the StreamWriter calls.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is as good as answered. I just did it in another way, though it may not be that good.

```
buildProgress.Enabled = true;
buildProgress.Maximum = lineCount;
for (int ctr = 0; ctr < lineCount; ctr++)
{   
    String outputPath = @"Q:\";
    StreamReader reader;
    String outputLine;
    console = new Process();
    console.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    console.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    console.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    console.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    console.Start();
    using (StreamWriter sw = console.StandardInput)
    {
        sw.AutoFlush = true;
        console.StandardInput.AutoFlush = true;
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(@"Q:\");       
            sw.WriteLine("msbuild /property:OutputPath=" + outputPath + @";OutputType=Library " + lines[ctr]);
            sw.Flush();
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
    reader = console.StandardOutput;
    outputLine = reader.ReadToEnd();
    console.WaitForExit();
    //if (console.HasExited)
    //{ 
        Console.Write(outputLine);
        //outputTextBox.Text += outputLine;
        pathToLog = @"Q:\" + fileList[ctr];
        File.Create(pathToLog).Dispose();
        File.WriteAllText(pathToLog, outputLine);
        buildProgress.Value = ctr;
        string[] readThatLog = File.ReadAllLines(pathToLog);
        foreach(string line in readThatLog)
        {
            if (line == "Build succeeded.")
            { 
                outputTextBox.AppendText(lines[ctr]);
                outputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);
                outputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else if (line == "Build FAILED.")
            {
                outputTextBox.AppendText(lines[ctr]);
                outputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + line);
                outputTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    //}
}
buildProgress.Value = 0;
buildProgress.Enabled = false;
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\nDONE!!!");
```